# Redux action buffer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using React / Redux to build my project. I have a checkbox that posts an action to toggle active / archive state of an item.

Since the checkbox can be toggled unlimited times (let's say the user is trigger happy), I wish to implement a timed buffer to ensure no calls are being made to the store and database API before 2 seconds has passed since last call.

Buffer concept

```
UI toggle --> 2sec. buffer --> database API call + dispatch

(0.00 sec) UI toggle on --> 2 sec. timer starts
(1.10 sec) UI toggle off --> 2 sec. timer restarts - action is being replaced
(2.30 sec) UI toggle on --> 2 sec. timer restarts - action is being replaced
(3.55 sec) UI toggle off --> 2 sec. timer restarts - action is being replaced
(5.56 sec) Timeout --> database API call + dispatch()
```

Are there any good and/or recommended ways of doing this?
I am already using redux-thunk.

Kind regards /K

Comment: Take a look at the lodash helpers "throttle" & "debounce", they are pretty straightforward to use: https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle

Comment: Thanks ScarySize! Will try that! :D /K